# How do i dynamically put delimiters in an array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

am new here so i am still trying to get a hang of things.
how do i dynamically add a delimiter like "|" after every 3 elements in an array in jquery so i can then explode the array and use the resulting arrays differently? 
i have

```
var items = {"010","Electronics","344","tv","car","truck"};
```

i want

```
var items = {"010,Electronics,344|tv,car,truck"}
```

the array could get bigger so i want to be able to count dynamically add "|" after 3 elements.
thanks a lot.

Comment: And where is the difficulty? Use for to iterate the array elements, and concatenate them. Create a new array for the result to push each concatenated string. Where is the problem? Can you write basic javascript? if not, don't try to get the answer here, and learn a little bit of js first

Comment: I think what you really mean is `["010","Electronics","344","tv","car","truck"];`

Comment: That is incorrect array syntax. You want square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Why do you just make it a two dimensional array and seperate things that way.

Comment: You want to join all the elements into one big string that is a single element in an array? What happens if I add a new element to the array? Does it get immediately consumed into the big string, or only after appending three new elements? Or do you only perform this transformation once, and never add new elements? (Then I'm not sure what you mean by "dynamically".)

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan yeah,thats what i really mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick method using `reduce`:

```
function join(arr) {
  return [arr.reduce(function(p, c, i) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) p.push([]);
    p[p.length - 1].push(c || ' ');
    return p;
  }, []).join('|')];
}

join(items); // [ "010,Electronics,344|tv,car,truck" ]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1bd56r3s/4/)

Comment: this doesnt work when one of the entries is empty like if instead of "344", you have " ".

Comment: Perhaps you should have included that edge case, because this solves the example in your question. What would the expected output look like with an empty element? @ordinaryman

Comment: @Andy...am sorry for not specifying initially...expected output should be ["010,Electronics, |tv,car,truck"]

Comment: @ordinaryman, updated answer. Note that if you have `null` or `0` that will have the result. You might want to do something different for those

Comment: @Andy...works perfectly the way i want...it works the way i want it with null and 0...what could i have done without u?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want to do

```
function foo(items, delimiter, everyX){
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        if(i == items.length-1){
            result += items[i]
        }else{
            if( (i+1) % everyX == 0 ){
                result += items[i] + delimiter;
            }else{
                result += items[i] + ",";
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}




var items = ["010","Electronics","344","tv","car","truck"];
foo(items, "|", 3);
```

Result:

```
"010,Electronics,344|tv,car,truck"
```

Comment: this doesnt work when one of the entries is empty like if instead of "344", you have " ".